# Javascript comparing number get from property of an Object as String

Tags: javascript, json, equality

I'm stuck for hours in a weird situation where one number property of a JSON that is received from the server fails a simple equality test.

```
var form =  {'answer':'','categoryDisplay':'dbAdmin','creationDate':null,'id':0,'question':'','techJobDisplay':null,'techJobId':65};

var selTechJobId = form.techJobId;

var thisVal = String(65);
var restoreVal = String(selTechJobId);

alert("thisVal : " + thisVal + " | typeof thisVal : " + typeof thisVal);
alert("restoreVal : " + restoreVal + " | typeof restoreVal : " + typeof restoreVal);

alert("thisVal === restoreVal : " + thisVal === restoreVal);
```

When I run this, the third alert display "false". To me it clearly should display "true". I'm obviously missing something.

I've been googling about this for hours and I see most of them is about type mismatch issue. As you can see, I explicitly convert them both to String so it shouldn't be the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using: `"thisVal === restoreVal : " + thisVal` you are concatening string, so you are comparing `"thisVal === restoreVal : 65"` with `"65"`

Comment: Geez. Really not good to code when you're hungry. Many thanks! Will accept after 5 mins

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs in the last alert in your code you have to parenthesis around the statement
after the + operator like this:

```
var form = {'answer':'','categoryDisplay':'dbAdmin','creationDate':null,'id':0,'question':'','techJobDisplay':null,'techJobId':65};

var selTechJobId = form.techJobId;

var thisVal = String(65);
var restoreVal = String(selTechJobId);

 alert("thisVal : " + thisVal + " | typeof thisVal : " + typeof thisVal);
  alert("restoreVal : " + restoreVal + " | typeof restoreVal : " + typeof restoreVal);



  alert("thisVal === restoreVal : " + (thisVal === restoreVal));
```

That way it doesn't try to add the value of the first part of the expression to thisVal before
evaluating it

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code

```
alert("thisVal === restoreVal : " + (thisVal === restoreVal));
```

cause in your variant you compare ""thisVal === restoreVal : 65" and "65" - they are not equal

http://jsbin.com/dowihoqizi/1/